# Add schema name to an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui

Using kendo, I need to send a server error back to the client via this object:

```
 public class callResult
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public int returnedID { get; set; }

    }
```

and wish the return object back to the client, would look like this
"error:{success:false,message:'invalid code'}"

But when i return the object from service like this

```
 return Json (error, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

My schema "error" is not being sent, just the properties of the object.

**How can I add an schema/name to my object ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix json result such as:

```
return Json(new {error = errorResult}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Yikes !! that was fast and effective (giggidity!!). Thanks.

Comment: I was looking for the same solution. Thanks mate :)